# The average of a function over a sphere tends to its value at the center, as the radius goes to zero

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

This question arose when I investigated into the proof of the mean-value property of a harmonic function. Let $u$ be a harmonic function of class $C^2$ defined on an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The mean-value property asserts that
$$u(x)=\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} u\mathrm{d}S,$$
where $\alpha(n)$ denotes the volume of a unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B(x,r)$ is a ball of center $x$ and radius $r$ that is contained in $U$. To prove, the author invoked the fact that
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)t^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,t)} u\mathrm{d}S=u(x).$$
Intuitively, this is absolutely right. But how do I prove it rigorously? Thanks.

Comment: Noticed that $\frac{1}{n\alpha(n) r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} dS=1$ and u is continuous at point x, then you can use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to finish the proof.

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|u(x)-u(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $y\in B(x,\delta)$. So, for $r<\delta$,
\begin{align}
\left|u(x) - \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} u\,\mathrm{d}S\right|
&= \left|\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}(u(x)-u)\,\mathrm{d}S\right|\\
&\le \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}|u(x)-u|\,\mathrm{d}S\\
&< \epsilon.
\end{align}